# How to add menu item classes in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following HTML code for menu.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <li class="nav-item mr-3">
    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#features">Features <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item mr-3">
    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#features">Pricing <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item mr-3">
    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#features">Download <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item mr-3">
    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#features">Contact <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Added **ul** class in the following file.
http://my_domain/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php

```
<ul id="%1$s" class="navbar-nav ml-auto">%3$s</ul>
```

How can I add **li** classes and **anchor** classes?

Comment: You must not change the WordPress core files. Once WordPress got updated to newer version all your changes will be gone

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam, How can i add my HTML classes then? Suggested me plz..

Comment: You should create a new theme / Child theme from your current theme.

Comment: Somebody answered my question earlier, that was worked me great. But somebody deleted, plz add again.

Comment: And Somebody made my question "-1", If i didn't ask in right way, plz edit my question but not make it "-1". Thanks for that..

Comment: You can do this by extending Walker_Nav_Menu class,  see this https://www.ibenic.com/how-to-create-wordpress-custom-menu-walker-nav-menu-class/ ,  https://www.microdot.io/simpler-wp-nav-menu-markup/

Comment: post your code here?

Answer (score 2):

Go to YOURSITEURL/wp-admin/nav-menus.php

open SCREEN OPTIONS make checked "CSS CLASSES" then you will see "CSS Classes (optional)"

field in each menu link.You can add your class in class filed of each menu item.

OR

You can add bellow function for adding class in **li** element This is how I would do it. Just add something like this to your functions.php file.

```
function atg_menu_classes($classes, $item, $args) {
  if($args->theme_location == 'secondary') {
    $classes[] = 'list-inline-item';
  }
  return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class','atg_menu_classes',1,3);
```

If you want class in **a** tag then add below code in functions.php

```
function add_link_atts($atts) {
  $atts['class'] = "nav-link";
  return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_link_atts');
```

If you want class in **ul** element.You can add below code in header area.

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'top-menu',
    'container' => false,
    'items_wrap' => '<ul class="nav your_custom_class">%3$s</ul>',
));
```